# Django : testing static files

Tags: django, testing

Using the testing framework (TestCase) of Django 1.3, I would like to run some tests on static files (i.e., files not necessarily served by django itself on prod but that can be served for debug (runserver)). 
But if I run

```
self.client.get("/static/somefile.json")
```

... I get a 404 error in my tests. (of course, this file is available on runserver)

Why not, but what would be the nicest way to check the presence of this json schema in my static files ?   (in my case, I would also like to test this public json schema against a generated json output, so I want the content of the file)

Comment: This happens because [Django tests run with `DEBUG = False` always, irrespective of your settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#other-test-conditions). I'm not sure what you should do though, so wait for a real answer :s

Comment: I had a scenario where I had to set `settings.DEBUG = False`. This is possible by `from django.test.utils import override_settings` and then decorating the test with `@override_settings(DEBUG=True)` [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#overriding-settings)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another method which I find slightly easier as there's less to type/import:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders

result = finders.find('css/base.css')
```

If the static file was found, it will return the full path to the file. If not found, it will return `None`

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#finders-module

---

As of Django 1.7+, you can also find out/test where Django is looking through the finders module:

```
searched_locations = finders.searched_locations
```

In addition to the `SimpleTestCase.assertTemplateUsed(response, template_name, msg_prefix='')` assertion provided by Django, you could also make use of:
`response.templates` from the Response class to get a list of templates that were used to render the response.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.templates

Comment: This throws a SuspiciousFileOperation in my test for uploaded content

Answer (score 9):

how about this:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage

absolute_path = finders.find('somefile.json')
assert staticfiles_storage.exists(absolute_path)
```

This uses the staticfiles finders to find a file called 'somefile.json' and then checks if the file actually exists on the storage you configured?

Comment: Not as transparent as I hoped but it should work. I will try to validate this soon. Thx

Comment: staticfiles_storage.exists() is likely to throw a SuspiciousFileOperation exception if you have set `STATIC_ROOT` different to `STATIC_URL` as the testcase doesn't collect staticfiles; you don't actually need this as `finders.find` will return none if the path is invalid

Answer (score 7):

You could use class `testing.StaticLiveServerTestCase` from the staticfiles module:
http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/contrib/staticfiles.html#specialized-test-case-to-support-live-testing

Comment: This is the right answer when using a live test server!

Answer (score 4):

As isbadawi comments, the test server always runs with `DEBUG = False`. So you can't rely on the DEBUG handling of static files, you need an explicit production-like way of handling them for the test to find them. You could have a special section in your `urls.py` that turns on the development `serve()` for when you run `test`:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    static_url = re.escape(settings.STATIC_URL.lstrip('/'))
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % static_url, 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
    )
```

Comment: +1 for ingenuity, but feels like it defeats the point of unittesting if you are changing the ernvironment variables to make the test pass

Answer (score 2):

This is for serving static files ONLY during development:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, for significant projects, I would offer the opinion that testing static files might be outside the scope of pure Django testing since Django's runserver is not intended to be used for serving static files. This kind of testing would usually be reserved for integration tests that involves testing your deployment more so than the development code.